# iOS Today Extension / widget -- location permissions?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, core-location, ios8-today-widget

I'm writing an app which is location-based, and includes a Today extension (widget)... What I can't seem to figure out is this.  When deciding whether to require access to location "always" versus "while using", does having the Today view active with my widget showing qualify as "using" the app?  In other words, as long as I only need the user's location when they have the widget visible in their Today view, is it sufficient just to have the "while using" permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's sufficient. I'm using the "while using" permission in my widget and did not have any problems with it.